# Scan and print full names in a list (C language)

Tags: c

I want to create a C program that can read 'n' number of full names from keyboard input and print them. I tried to use `fgets()`, but couldn't figure out how to scan multiple entries, so I ended up writing the code below.

The issue is, it takes the names as input and just prints garbage values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char name[64][64],sur[15][15],a[3];

    printf("How many names? ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter names:\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s%s",name[i],sur[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a[3]=' ';
        strcat(name[i],a);
        strcat(name[i],sur[i]);
    }

    printf("\nThe names are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",name[i]);
    }
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a[3]=' ';` in your code is problamatic. Use `a[0]` and make `a[1]` as NULL

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings (usually by adding `-Wall`). They will catch things like the `a[3] = ' '` problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@16tons addresses the most obvious issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41727291/14660), but there are lurking memory problems. The `scanf` and `strcat` calls are vulnerable to [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). They will not limit themselves to just the allocated memory.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%s%s",name[i],sur[i]);
}
```

This will try to put any number of input characters into `name[i]` and `sur[i]` which can only hold strings of 63 and 14 characters respectively. That means [Hubert Wolfe­schlegel­stein­hausen­berger­dorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubert_Blaine_Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff,_Sr.) will cause `name[i]` to contain `"Hubert\0"` and `sur[i]` will contain `"Wolfe­schlegel­st"` (no null byte) and the rest will spill over into adjacent memory causing problems. Because of the lack of a null byte, trying to use `sur[i]` as a string will result in reading whatever garbage is after it.

Same with `strcat`.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    a[0]=' ';
    a[1]='\0';
    strcat(name[i],a);
    strcat(name[i],sur[i]);
}
```

If `name[i]` is already full, adding to the end of it will overflow its buffer scribbling over adjacent memory and causing weird problems.

```
How many names? 3

Enter names:
Hubert Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff
Hubert Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff
Hubert Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff

The names are:
Hubert WolfeschlegelstWolfeschlegelstWolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff WolfeschlegelstWolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff
gerdorff WolfeschlegelstWolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff
Hubert Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff
```

---

To avoid this, `scanf` must be limited to the buffer size. When using `strcat`, the string being added to must have sufficient space to accept the new characters.

Since you're using `name[i]` to store both the first name and then the full name, it's important that you limit the size of the first name to leave space for the last time. Since `sur[i]` can have 14 characters, and `name[i]` can have 63, that's 63 - 14 or 49. Don't forget the space! 48.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%48s%14s",name[i],sur[i]);
}
```

This ensures that `scanf` will read no more than 48 characters into `name[i]` (using 49 bytes because of the null byte) and no more than 14 into `sur[i]` (using 15).

Now your `strcat`s are safe. We know for sure `name[i]` has the space to accept a space and `sur[i]` on the end. 48 (max chars already in `name[i]`) + 1 (the space) + 14 (max in `sur[i]`) + 1 (null byte) = 64.

While your technique saves some memory, it's ***much*** safer to have separate `given` and `surname` variables which are concatenated into a fresh `name` variable. Then all you need to do is add up the sizes of `given`, `surname`, and the space to know how big `name` should be. The limits on `scanf` are simply the size of the buffers. No needing to remember that one variable has to keep some extra space around, nor having to redo all those calculations (or more likely forget to redo them) if `surname` gets bigger.

For your particular purposes, the `strcat`s are unnecessary. `printf` can do it safer.

```
printf("\nThe names are:\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    printf("%s %s\n",name[i], sur[i]);
}
```

It's safer, easier, and faster to print a bunch of variables to a stream than to concatenate them together and then print them.

Comment: You're right, I didn't consider the memory management. Thank you for your advice. I'll edit the program accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, use `a[0]` as space and make `a[1]` null. Code below works.

```
int main()
{
    int n,i;
    char name[64][64],sur[15][15],a[3];

    printf("How many names? ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("\nEnter names:\n");

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%s%s",name[i],sur[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a[0]=' ';
        a[1]='\0';
        strcat(name[i],a);
        strcat(name[i],sur[i]);
    }

    printf("\nThe names are:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",name[i]);
    }
    getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood how to solve the issue.

Comment: There's no need for `a`, `strcat(name[i], " ")` works fine. Note that `scanf` and `strcat` still contain the potential for buffer overflow. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41727793/14660).